# VTune OSX client preferences -- save preferences across sessions

Tags: intel-vtune

I use the Intel VTune OSX client to view profiles collected on a linux machine. I like to view my data in certain ways -- how I see the threads sorted in a non-default way, how time is displayed and sorted in the Bottom-Up view. I spend non-trivial time reconfiguring the UI. Is there a way to save preferences such as these across VTune sessions and profiles?

Comment: Can you list particular settings you'd like to save? VTune is automatically saving the selected grouping, columns order and few other things.

Comment: There's two main ones that come to mind: the ordering of the threads listed in the bottom pane in Bottom-Up (I personally want sort by name, ascending) and a nice-to-have would be preserving the interface tweaks (e.g., the adjusted sizes of the different UI panes such as the width of the Project Navigator sidebar, which I don't use and tend to minimize).